# Unable to route traffic to docker container via traefik

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm trying to route traffic from my domain foobar.com to the backend container through traefik as a reverse proxy. But I cannot see the problem! Can anyone help?

My traefik.toml file looks like this:

```
debug = true

logLevel = "ERROR"

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  domain = "foobar.com"
  watch = true
  exposedByDefault = false
  network = "web"


[acme]
  email = "my-email-here@gmail.com"
  storage = "acme.json"
  entryPoint = "https"
  onHostRule = true

[acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"
```

My docker-compose for traefik:

```
version: '2'                                                

    services:                                                   
      traefik:                                                  
        image: traefik:latest                                   
        restart: always                                         
        command: --docker --web                                 
        ports:                                                  
          - 80:80                                               
          - 443:443                                             
          - 8080:8080                                           
        networks:                                               
          - web                                                 
        volumes:                                                
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock           
          - /home/dockerfiles/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
          - /home/dockerfiles/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json      
        container_name: traefik                                 

    networks:                                                   
      web:                                                      
        external: true
```

I'm trying to setup a sample ghost blog. The docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: '2.1'

services:

  ghost:
    image: ghost:1-alpine
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "2368"
    labels:
      - traefik.docker.network=web
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:foobar.com
      - traefik.port=2368
      - traefik.protocol=http
      - traefik.backend=ghost
    networks:
      - web

networks:
  web:
   external: true
```

Comment: from `traefik` container. can you access `ghost:2368` through `telnet` or `curl` ? if no, what is the response ?

Comment: No :/ I get he following message:

curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.28.0.3 port 2268: Connection refused

The ip of the ghost container is "172.28.0.3" according to docker inspect and the traefik container has "172.28.0.2". So they are on the same subnet, and should be able to reach each other.

Comment: If I bind the ghost container port to the host machine (server), I am able to reach it from my machine on the servers host ip+port number. The same goes with the traefik container. I am able to get the traefik dashboard up on port 8080.